# VS Code file explorer won't show certain files or directories in some projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, cordova-win10

I have what appears to be a weird problem. In some project folders when I open them in VS Code I don't see the entire directory tree in the file explorer, some folders and files are missing, and if I open some folders, content is empty, quite annoying. I have looked at Files: Excluded in the Settings and everything is default. If I open the folder through the File menu option I see the entire content of the directory alright. I am on win10 and the project is C#. Any ideas what might be wrong?
Edit: Should mention I am using git. I have these extensions inststalled: .NET Core Test Explorer, C#, C# extensions, Debugger for Unity, Dotnet core commands, Dotnet Core Essentials, Git History, GitLens, Jira and Bitbucket, Prettier, Unity Code Snippets, Unity Snippets, YAML

Comment: Is it just files or folders? i.e, can you see folders but not the contents inside, or can you see files but no folders (and none of the files inside of those folders ofc)

Comment: It is a mix of both files and folders, i.e. I can see some files and some folders, but some are invisible of both kinds, very frustrating. In some cases I can see the folders but they have no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else runs into the same issue. Turns out not all excluded files show up in the Settings. The file under .vscode called settings.json likely contains a lot longer list, in my case all the files types and folders I was missing in my view was on that hidden list.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was `exclude .gitignore` setting, that was set to true.
Here's the setting's ID: `explorer.excludeGitIgnore`.